# Misaligned columns in Primefaces datatable

Tags: primefaces, primefaces-datatable

I'm trying to make a datatable showing column as easy as possible - like auto width.

It misaligns the columns compared to the header, like these:

[image: example]

My code looks like this:

```html
<p:dataTable id="datalist2" value="#{item.formItemCollection}"
    var="item2" scrollable="true" scrollHeight="100" tableStyle="width:auto" 
    emptyMessage="#{bundle.EmptyMessage}" >
```

```html
<ui:include src="/view/formItem/formItemListRow.xhtml">
    <ui:param name="rowItem" value="#{item2}"/>  
    <ui:param name="controller" value="#{formItemController}"/>  
</ui:include>
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. What version do you use? What theme? What custom CSS?

Comment: Does removing `tableStyle="width:auto"` help?